# Unable to load namespaced class in PHP 5.3.27

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, fatal-error

I have an issue where I seem to be unable to load a namespace that I have created. I have read a bit about namespaces on SO, but I can't see what I am missing in this case.

This is my calling code:

```
<?php

use \CRMPicco\User\AlertReminder;
$alert_reminder = new AlertReminder($userObj);

?>
```

This is my namespaced code:

```
<?php
namespace CRMPicco\User;

class AlertReminder
{

}
```

This is my error:

> Fatal error: Class 'CRMPicco\User\AlertReminder' not found in
>   /var/www/vhosts/dev/web/login.inc.php on line 324

Line 324 is the `new AlertReminder` line.

Comment: Remove the leading backslash after `use`.

Comment: @Jon would I have to explicity _include_ it though? Wouldn't this load with the autoloader?

Comment: Yes, this would load with an autoloader if you had set up and autoloader and the autoloader can correctly load the file. Have you?

Comment: @Jon removing the leading baskslash has no effect unfortunately.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, you've pointed me in the right direction. We have some cleansing of classnames passed to our custom autoloader that was preventing this loading. I have restructured the class and it now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to some classname cleansing in my custom autoloader, which prevented the class from loading.

I refactored the class into another package and it now works as expected.